# Getting Value From Code Behind On DropDown Value Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

`ProductList` is a dropdownlist containing three values `1`, `2`, and `3`. When I change the dropdown value the `change` function is firing but i couldn't get a return value from the .cs file.

```js
$("#ProductList").change(function(data) {
  debugger;
  var value = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<%= ResolveUrl("PracticeForm.aspx/getValue") %>",
    data: value,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      var value = response.d;
      alert(value);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('there is some error');
    }
  });
```

```csharp
[WebMethod()]
public static string GetValue(string value)
{
  string val = string.Empty;
  var result = new { val };
  if (value == "1")
  {
    result = new { val = "Seleted value is " + value };
  }
  else if (value == "2")
  {
    result = new { val = "Seleted value is " + value };
  }
  else if (value == "3")
  {
      result = new { val = "Seleted value is " + value };
  }
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

Comment: You need to debug this to find an error which can be investigated. Put a breakpoint in the server side logic and step through the C# code, and also check the console in the browser dev tools to check for errors there. I would guess that `data: value` needs to be `data: { value: value }` and `var value = response.d;` needs to be `var value = response.val;`

Comment: POST http://localhost:55071/PracticeForm.aspx/getValue 500 (Internal Server Error)
I am getting this error on console